# Is this a metric?

Tags: linear-algebra, metric-spaces

> Let $d:\mathbb{Z}$ $\times$ $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{≥0}$
>
> $d(x,y)=
> \begin{cases}
> 0,& \text{if $x=y$},\\
> 2^{-m},&\text{if $x≠y$ with $2^m$ divides $y-x$ and $2^{m+1}$ does not divide $y-x$}
> \end{cases}$

Now $d(x,y)=0$ iff $x=y$ is clear from the condition of the metric,

$d(x,y)=d(y,x)=2^{-m}$
and then triangle inequality looks good to me.

But this second condition confuses me a little bit, I think there has to be more work behind it, but I'm not sure what I have to consider. Any help please?

Comment: You should check me. But I believe this is called the $2$-adic metric (you can do it with any prime $p$).

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/p-adicNorm.html (this website defines it for any rational number but I guess it can be useful)